# How focus paritcular html component in page with Angular?

Tags: angular6, angular5

I want to scroll down to page. When I clicked anchor , I want to stay on same page but focus on partivular element or page down. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create an element reference in your component like this

```
@ViewChild('whatever') myElement: ElementRef;
```

Bind it to the html element like this

```
<input #whatever />
```

Then you should be able to call focus to it like this.

```
function focusWhatever() {
    this.myElement.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Element References are a powerful tool in Angular for accessing DOM elements directly, particularly for stuff like this. Read more about them [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef).

Read more about the el.focus() DOM API method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).